# Grouping values in a variable?

Tags: vba

If I had a file I wanted to cut into a bunch of files based on column A values, would it be possible to put certain values into an array to group as one file--instead of separate files?

for example, I'd like to do something like this to group, but I don't know how to craft the IF statement when the array prints to the template I'm using?

```
  Dim SharedServices As Variant
  SharedServices = "Manager 1, Manager 3, Manager 5, Manager 9"
```

and then

```
    If Data(i, 1) <> SharedServices Then

        For sourceCol = 1 To UBound(Data, 2)
          Dest.Offset(destRow, destCol) = Data(sourceRow, sourceCol)
          destCol = destcol + 1
        Next

        destRow = DestRow + 1
    Else
    'Group SharedServices into one file
    End If
    Next
```

I can't quite figure out how to establish the grouping of the `SharedServices` array into one file

script:

```
    Option Explicit

Sub Main()
   Dim wb As Workbook
   Dim Data, Last, Login
   Dim sourceRow As Long, destRow As Long, sourceCol As Long, destCol As Long
   Dim Dest As Range
   Dim SharedServices As Variant
   SharedServices = "manager 1, manager 3, manager 7, manager 11"
   Set wb = Workbooks("Template.xlsx")

   Set Dest = wb.Sheets("Full Roster").Range("A3")

   With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Full Roster")
       Data = .Range("DC3", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
   End With
   wb.Activate
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False   
      For sourceRow = 1 To UBound(Data)
        If Data(sourceRow, 1) <> Last Then
          If sourceRow > 1 Then  
            Dest.Select
            wb.SaveCopyAs ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & _
            ValidFileName(Last & " - Validation.xlsx")
          End If

          With Sheets("Exempt Population")
             .Rows(3 & ":" & .Rows.Count).ClearContents
          End With

          Last = Data(sourceRow, 1)
          destRow = 0
       End If

       destCol = 0

       If Data(sourceRow, 1) <> SharedServices Then
          For sourceCol = 1 To UBound(Data, 2)
              Dest.Offset(destRow, destCol) = Data(sourceRow, sourceCol)
              destCol = destCol + 1
          Next
          sourceRow = sourceRow + 1
        Else
            'Group SharedServices into one file
        End If
    Next
    SaveCopy wb, Login, Last '<< save the last report        
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want to check if the items in `Data` are in your list of SharedServices then one way is to turn it into a "proper" array, viz:

```
Dim SharedServices As Variant

SharedServices = Array("Manager 1", "Manager 3", "Manager 5", "Manager 9")

If IsNumeric(Application.Match(data(i, 1), SharedServices, 0)) Then 'array item is in SharedServices
    'do whatever
End If
```

Comment: Actually looks like you are checking that they are not in the array, but hopefully you get the logic.

Comment: so would I put the array print in there, and then in the `Else` section, put the array in print in, as well?

Comment: What do you mean by "array print"?

Comment: there's 35 managers in column A `Data(i,1)`, and each manager will have a file made for them based on array created by `Last`. I want to make sure that the data printed to `Wb` is each separate manager, but when it's one of the managers in `SharedServices` I want it to combine all of those managers into one file, not separate files